# List custom setting works with getOrgDefaults() - should it?

Tags: apex, customsetting

I have checked the documentation, and getOrgDefaults() is only listed as a hierarchy custom setting method. (https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_methods_system_custom_settings.htm) But I made a LIST custom setting with two entries and getOrgDefaults() returns the first one I created.

Does this sound like expected behavior? A bug? Can anyone recreate this situation with a list custom setting?

Comment: Interesting hack .Anything undocumented i make as practice not to use as if it breaks i will not have rights to later raise a case with SFDC

Comment: It's not a hack because it's not intentional. I just found that it worked, but I am not planning to use it in production code. I'm asking the question to find out if anyone else experiences the same thing, and if they do, then it may be a bug.